# Generate ggplot and return output from function call

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, environment

I've got a problem when creating a ggplot as a side-effect of a function call:

MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
  y = rnorm(10, 11:20),
  id = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace= T))

MegaFunction <- function(df) {
  # do something to the data
  df$y <- df$y - 10
  # plot it
  NicePlot(df)
  # return output
  return(df)
}

NicePlot <- function(x) {
  ggplot(x, aes(x = x, y = y, col = id)) +
    geom_point()
}

MegaFunction(dat)  # returns values, but doesn't plot
out <- MegaFunction(dat)  # returns values as out
NicePlot(out)      # plots values successfully
```

So the problem is that I can not create the plots using MegaFunction, but I can do it when I call NicePlot on the output of MegaFunction (as expected). This probably has something to do with the environment the function is called from, but I cannot figure it out. Any ideas? In base R this does work.

Comment: From `MegaFunction` return: `return(list(plotResult = NicePlot(df), dataResult = df))`

Comment: Use `print(NicePlot(df))` inside `MegaFunction`

Comment: @Marco thanks! That works and is nice and simple. If you want you can enter it as an answer that I will mark as "the answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marco Sandri pointed out, I simply had to wrap the wrapper function in a `print` command.

```
print(NicePlot(df))
```